# How to make the method "toString" private?

Tags: javascript

How for "Weapon" implement the method "toString", which will be unavailable for Object.keys ().

```js
function Weapon(name,damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.toString = function () {
        return this.name + this.damage + " damage";
    }
}
var bow = new Weapon(' Golden bow, ',20);
var sword = new Weapon(' Magic sword, ', 40);
console.log(bow.toString());
console.log(sword.toString());
Object.defineProperty(Weapon, "toString", {enumerable: false});
```

Comment: `Weapon.prototype.toString = ...`

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(Weapon, "toString", {enumerable: false});` makes no sense. The `toString` property you want to change is defined on `bow` and `sword`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: If you want privacy you need to use closures. Non enumerability is not the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From MDN about `Object.keys()`:

> `Object.keys()` returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object.

So either make the property **non-enumerable**:

```
function Weapon(name,damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
      value: function () {
        return this.name + this.damage + " damage";
      },
      // enumerable: false, // is implicitly set
    });
}
```

Or make it ***not* an "own" property** by defining it on the prototype:

```
function Weapon(name,damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
}

Weapon.prototype.toString = function () {
  return this.name + this.damage + " damage";
};
```

---

You get both "for free" if you use `class` syntax:

```
class Weapon {
  constructor(name,damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  toString()
    return this.name + this.damage + " damage";
  }
}
```

`toString` will be defined on the prototype and it won't be enumerable.